# Rust - Mix default macro and personal default implementation

Tags: rust, macros, default

I want to know if it's possible to let Rust define the default implementation for my structure with the macro `#[derive(Default)]` but define some default values for some fields.

I want to do this to avoid to define the default values of all fields when Rust could do it.

Thanks for your time

Comment: why not implementing it yoursefl in this case ?!?

Comment: @Stargateur Because I have only one field which have a particular value. I don't want to write code for other fields if Rust can do it for me.

Comment: you don't need a macro for that, it's overkill and will be annoying to maintain

Comment: @Stargateur Can you provide me more details on what is your solution please

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9b7da62073ef46d8f7a4adc06b13f15

Comment: The default ˋderive` are simple and non configurable by design There are many crates providing alternative derives for standard traits.

Comment: Yep I just found this : https://github.com/idanarye/rust-smart-default it's awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `derive(Default)` is all-or-nothing.

However, you can initialize `Default`able fields using `field: Default::default()` (which may already be simple enough). You could use this fact to write a macro that takes all `Default`able fields and initializes them, e.g.:

```
macro_rules! defaultable{
    (
        $t: ty,
        @default($($default_field:ident,)*)
        @custom($($custom_field:ident = $custom_value:expr,)*)
    )
    => {
    impl Default for $t {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Self {
                $($default_field: Default::default(),)*
                $($custom_field: $custom_value,)*
            }
        }
    }
}}

struct S {
    n1: usize,
    n2: usize,
    b: bool,
    non_default: usize,
}

defaultable!(S, @default(n1, n2, b,) @custom(non_default=42,));

fn main() {
    let s : S = Default::default();
    println!("{}", s.non_default);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your example. I just found this : https://github.com/idanarye/rust-smart-default. Which seems really cool.